# currentUser global is null. I can't figure out why

Tags: templating, usermodel

Does anyone know why `currentUser` would return null? I'm logged in as an admin.. actually the only user.

I've cleared cache, logged out and back in, etc. I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm trying to set an edit link for an entry like so:

```
{% if currentUser %}
    <a href="{{ entry.cpEditUrl }}">
        Edit
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

And also tried this:

```
{% if entry.isEditable() %}
    <a href="{{ entry.cpEditUrl }}">
        Edit
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

Neither are working. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this in the context or a normal template request? i.e. you're not doing something edge case like trying to add this code inside of a redirect Twig tag or something similar?

Comment: Normal template request. It was working fine the other day. I have looked through all my git commits, turned off plugins, etc and I cannot get it working again.

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious, but you're positive you're logged in?

Comment: Yes, absolutely positive.

Comment: Did you happen to update Craft between the time it was working and now?  If so, do you remember the version you were on?

Comment: I may have figured it out. I was logged in with non-www. But going to the front end with www. Is there a way to make Craft not care about www?

Comment: You'd be better off picking either www or non-www as the canonical domain and forcing a rewrite from the other to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way - better for SEO as well because Google will index both as 2 separate sites instead of 1.

Comment: Be sure and add an official answer as well. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Per Brad's request. I am answering my own question.

I figured out that I was logging in via non-www, and accessing the site at www.

So the official answer is to choose either www or non-www. I chose to remove the www from the URL.

Here's my .htaccess for that, including allowing for fonts to be accessed cross domain, as I had issues with this as well.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(eot|ttf|otf|woff|svg)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

**Note!!!** Once this is done, make sure to clear your Craft cache., especially if using fonts/font-icons.